# items from traits can only be used if the trait is in scope

Tags: multithreading, rust, async-await

I am learning futures and threads in rust with this example, but this does not compile and I do not understand why.

```rust
use futures::future::Future;
use futures_cpupool::{CpuFuture, CpuPool};
use notify::{RecursiveMode, Watcher, watcher};

use std::{thread, time};

fn main() {
    let pool = CpuPool::new(10);

    let mut handles = Vec::new();

    for i in 0..10 {
        let i = i.clone();
        let handle: CpuFuture<(), ()> = pool.spawn_fn(move || {
            loop {
                println!("{}", i);

            }
            Ok(())
        });

        handles.push(handle);
    }

    thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_secs(2));

     for handle in handles {
         handle.wait().unwrap();
     }
}
```

error:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `wait` found for struct `CpuFuture` in the current scope
   --> src/main.rs:28:17
    |
28  |          handle.wait().unwrap();
    |                 ^^^^ method not found in `CpuFuture<(), ()>`
    |
   ::: /home/placek/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/futures-0.1.31/src/future/mod.rs:297:8
    |
297 |     fn wait(self) -> result::Result<Self::Item, Self::Error>
    |        ---- the method is available for `CpuFuture<(), ()>` here
    |
    = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is in scope
help: the following trait is implemented but not in scope; perhaps add a `use` for it:
    |
2   | use futures::future::Future;
    |
```

I have `Future` in scope so I think it should work, also I checked that CpuFuture implements `Future` trait.

Here is my cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "folderWatcher"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
notify = "4.0.12"
futures-cpupool = "0.1.7"
futures = "0.3.25"
```

Also I want to ask if it is required to explicitly start each Future?

Comment: Please include your `Cargo.toml`.

Comment: `futures-cpupool` is 5 years old and deprecated. Is there a reason you can't upgrade?

Comment: @isaactfa i did not know that, but I am looking for comfortable way to handling multithreading in my programs. I mean that asynchronous programming is not enough solution, because I waste my cpu cores. Can you give me any advice?

Comment: It kinda depends on your application. [Rayon](https://lib.rs/crates/rayon) tends to be the canonical high-level multithreading, data parallelism library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`futures-cpupool` requires `futures` version `0.1`, and version `0.3.25` is incompatible with it. So downgrade futures:

```ini
futures = "0.1"
```

However, the real problem is `futures-cpupool` being too old, as @isaactfa said.